# How can I custom the links in an NgbPagination?

Tags: angular, pagination, jhipster, ng-bootstrap

I am currently working on an angular project (actually it is done with Jhipster), and there are some components which use pagination in this app.
I realized that, when I right-click on a link of one of the pages, I am redirected to the home.

For example, let's say I have 5 pages in my pagination. If I open the link of the fifth in a new tab, I expect my new tab to redirect to the fifth page, but it redirects me to my home.

Is it possible to set the links of each page ? Or is it against best practices ?

I hope I've been clear enough, please do not hesitate to ask me for more information if needed.

Regards

Comment: To achieve this you need to create your own paginator and for pagination, you have to create child routes. In this way when you click any page number you will be redirected to the respected page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MukeshKumar. Is it acceptable to inherit the NgpPagination component to add some custom behavior ?